# Jam signals in csma/cd

Tags: cisco

Given that collisions happen in half-duplex setups, how can a device receive the jamming signal while it's transmitting data?

EDIT: Is it received on the TX- RX- wires?

Comment: The sending host actually listens while it sends.

Comment: In half-duplex, only one device at a time can send. There is a difference. You cannot send and receive a frame at the same time, but you can listen while sending. If another device is sending, and you hear it sending, then you cannot start sending. A collision occurs if one device is sending, but another device has not yet heard that and starts sending, when one of the devices hears that the other is also sending, the device sends a jam because it has detected a collision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CSMA/CD once a collision is detected, **the colliding devices send a jam signal**.
Assuming you know the collision detection method used by CSMA/CD, the jam signals generated after collision informs the devices that a collision has occurred and invokes a **random backoff algorithm** which forces the devices on the Ethernet **not to send** any data until their timer expires. (everyone has a random timer value)

> Once a transmitting device detects collision which is by examining the data over the
>   Ethernet and identifying that it's not the data it has send, **it does
>   receive the jamming signal** otherwise collision will keep happening. As
>   the jam signal is generated after collision hence the devices ideally
>   wont be sending any data during that time.

Comment: Look in half duplex you cannot send and receive different frames reliably since there is a single channel but you can read/examine the data on that channel. Even when a transmitting device is sending data via tx it keeps examining the channel via its rx to monitor collision. And as soon as a collision is detected by the transmitting device itself, random backoff algorithm is invoked.

Comment: @Lijok, ethernet runs on many different layer-1 media. It was originally specified for coax, where there are no pairs. Don't get stuck on ethernet over UTP. Also, depending on the medium (e.g. 1000BASE-T, the most common today), it may use all four pairs for both sending and receiving.